# Decremental multiplication in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Below is my sample dataframe `df`, with many variables where `C` is one among them, the length of the column in a variable.

```
 ID C
 1  0
 2  1.47349678
 3  0
 4  0
 5  0
 6  0
 7  0
 8  0
 9  0
10  0
11  0
12  0
13  0
14  0
16  1.987
17  0
18  0
19  0
20  0
21  0
22  0
23  0
24  0
25  0
26  0
27  0
```

I need to create another variable `C_C` where it consists of product of `C`and a **decremental factor by 0.1**.
The multiplication has to be done only for the count of `10` values of `C_C` from the point where there is a value of `C`other than `0`. Also the result has to be stored from the next data point. i.e If `C !=0` is found at `Id ==2` then the product must be stored from `ID==3`
If there are less than `10` continuous zeroes after a non zero number would the count just reset to the new value of `C`, and if there is no further data found the multiplication will stop.

**Expected Result**

```
   ID   C              C_C
   1    0              0
   2    1.47349678     0
   3    0              1.47349678
   4    0              1.326147102
   5    0              1.178797424
   6    0              1.031447746
   7    0              0.884098068
   8    0              0.73674839
   9    0              0.589398712
  10    0              0.442049034
  11    0              0.294699356
  12    0              0.147349678
  13    0              0
  14    0              0
  16    1.987          0
  17    0              1.987
  18    0              1.7883
  19    0              1.5896
  20    0              1.3909
  21    0              1.1922
  22    0              0.9935
  23    0              0.7948
  24    0              0.5961
  25    0              0.3974
  26    0              0.1987
  27    0               0
```

**Observation from the Required Result**
1. Value in `C` which is not `0`is enocunter at `ID = 2`, so the product is being stored from `ID == 3` i.e `C_C3`.
2. `C_C3 == C2 * 1`, `C_C4 == C2*0.9`, `C_C5 == C2 * 0.8`......`C_C12 == C*0.1`, 
   `C_C13 == C2 *0`.
3.  Similarly `C_C17 == C16 * 1`, `C_C18 == C16*0.9`, `C_C19 == C16 *0.8`, .... `C_C26 == C16 *0.1`, `C_C27 == C16*0`

Thanks!

Comment: If there are less than 10 continuous zeroes after a non zero number would the count just reset ?

Comment: @RonakShah Yeah, I I forgot to mention that. The count should reset new value of `C` for multiplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)   
df$group = cumsum(dt$C>0)
df = df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(value=sum(C)) %>%
  mutate(n=1.1-0.1*(row_number()-1)) %>% mutate(n=ifelse(n<0|value==0|n==1.1,0,n)) %>%
  mutate(C_C = n*value) %>% ungroup() %>% select(-n,-group,-value) %>% as.data.frame()

   ID     C    C_C
1   1 0.000 0.0000
2   2 1.473 0.0000
3   3 0.000 1.4735
4   4 0.000 1.3261
5   5 0.000 1.1788
6   6 0.000 1.0314
7   7 0.000 0.8841
8   8 0.000 0.7367
9   9 0.000 0.5894
10 10 0.000 0.4420
11 11 0.000 0.2947
12 12 0.000 0.1473
13 13 0.000 0.0000
14 14 0.000 0.0000
15 16 1.987 0.0000
16 17 0.000 1.9870
17 18 0.000 1.7883
18 19 0.000 1.5896
19 20 0.000 1.3909
20 21 0.000 1.1922
21 22 0.000 0.9935
22 23 0.000 0.7948
23 24 0.000 0.5961
24 25 0.000 0.3974
25 26 0.000 0.1987
26 27 0.000 0.0000
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, But `C_C3 == C2 * 1`  but as per your code its `C_C3 == C *0.9`.

Comment: sorry, I overlooked that. Corrected by setting 1 to 1.1

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly.

Comment: Great, glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

A little lengthy procedure with `sapply` from base R

```
vals <- which(df$C != 0)
values <- c(sapply(df$C[vals], function(x) x * rev(seq(0.1, 1.0, 0.1))))
inds <- c(sapply(vals + 1, function(x) seq(x, x+9)))
df$C_C <- 0
df$C_C[inds] <- values
df$C_C

# [1] 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.4734968 1.3261471 1.1787974 1.0314477 0.8840981
# [8] 0.7367484 0.5893987 0.4420490 0.2946994 0.1473497 0.0000000 0.0000000
#[15] 0.0000000 1.9870000 1.7883000 1.5896000 1.3909000 1.1922000 0.9935000
#[22] 0.7948000 0.5961000 0.3974000 0.1987000 0.0000000
```

Here, we first find out indices which are not equal to 0 (`vals`), get their respective values (`df$C[vals]`) and for each value we multiply it by 1.0, 0.9, 0.8.....etc. We now have all the `values` which we need , now to place these `values` we generate its respective indices (`inds`) using `seq` function. We can now just assign the `values` at their respective indices (`inds`) and assign 0 to remaining values.

Comment: Thanks for the solution!!, My data frame is around 850K data points, Your code is being executed for data points around 150K, but for my data frame of 850K, its throwing an error of unequal column lengths.